# How to apply the same cat.codes to 2 different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I have 2 dataframes `X_train` and `X_test`. These 2 dataframes have the same columns.

There is 1 column called `levels` that needs to be changed from `str` to `int`. However, each dataframe's `levels` columns has different unique values:

`X_train` has: ['Level 0', 'Level 10', 'Level 30'] as unique values.

`X_test` has: ['Level 20', 'Level 40'] as unique values.

The goal is 1) Combine the unique values from both `X_train` and `X_test`, and then 2) apply the `cat.codes` to both dataframes so that they are consistent. How would I do that? Basically the `cat.codes` that are applied to both dataframes will be as follows, even though 1 dataframe may not have values the other dataframe has:

```
{0: 'Level 0', 1: 'Level 10', 2: 'Level 20', 3: 'Level 30', 4: 'Level 40'}
```

Right now I only have the below but I'm not sure how to get the unique values of both `cat.codes`.

```
X_train['levels'] = X_train['levels'].astype('category').cat.codes
X_test['levels'] = X_test['levels'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CategoricalDtype` to control the codes:

```
lst = sorted(set(X_train['levels'].dropna().unique())
             | set(X_test['levels'].dropna().unique()))
lvl = pd.CategoricalDtype(lst, ordered=True)

X_train['codes'] = X_train['levels'].astype(lvl).cat.codes
X_test['codes'] = X_test['levels'].astype(lvl).cat.codes
```

Output:

```
>>> X_train
     levels  codes
0   Level 0      0
1  Level 10      1
2  Level 30      3

>>> X_test
     levels  codes
0  Level 20      2
1  Level 40      4
2       NaN     -1
```

Comment: 2 followups, 1) if you didnt know what the `lst` of unique values were beforehand, how would you get them? im thinking `set(X_train['levels'].unique() + X_test['levels'].unique())`? 2) If there were NAN values in the columns, would it automatically code it as `{-1: NAN}`?

Comment: 1) Build your list as you want and sort them if needed. 2) Exact, nan is always -1 in CategoricalIndex. I updated my answer according your comment. Can you check it please?